# How to prevent parent click event in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

```js
onParentClick = () => {
  console.log('Parent is triggered');
}

onChildClick = (event) => {
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log('Child is triggered');
}
```

```html
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={()=> this.onParentClick()}>
  <View>
    <Text>How to prevent parent click event</Text>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={(event)=> this.onChildClick(event)}>
      <Text> Click Me </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
<!-- edit description:- there was this end curly brace missing in above,
 however the snippet will not run because the language js will not 
support it and language html will not be able to format it correctly or run it.
(need to run the snippet on the react native environment like code-pen)  -->
```

Expected: On click of "Click Me", onChildClick() must be called

Issue: On click of "Click Me", onParentClick() is called.

How to prevent parents click event on click of "Click Me"?

Result which I get on click of parent is "Parent is triggered" and it works perfect.

But on click on child the result I get is "Parent is triggered".

I guess onChildClick() is not being triggered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React - carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52979157/react-carousel)

Comment: Please note the OP is using React Native, `stopPropagation` is a DOM method.    I don't use react native, but from what I can tell it still contains currentTarget & target, so using the `React - carousel` duplicate above is most likely what the OP is wanting.

Comment: For parent view use simple <View> with `pointerEvents='box-none'` prop

Answer (score 24):

Old question, but I faced the same issue and in my case, the problem was:

```
import {TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import {TouchableWithoutFeedback} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

This weird import happened due to automatic suggestion by eslint. Somehow these libraries don't play nicely together, so I changed the above to:

```
import {TouchableOpacity, TouchableWithoutFeedback} from 'react-native';
```

Comment: only the 725th time I'm importing react native components from react-native-gesture-handler and facing issues

Comment: `Saviour!! `

Comment: Oh my... I spend over an hour yesterday figuring out why my `TouchableOpacity` ignores `width: '100%'`. It was exactly because of this import. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! I had a similar situation when using `styled-components`. The fix was to either import `TouchableOpacity` from `react-native` or to use  TouchableOpacity from `react-native-gesture-handler` when defining a styled component. I.e. `import {TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native-gesture-handler'` and then `const Container = styled(TouchableOpacity)`

Answer (score 4):

With `event.stopPropagation` you can stop event from propagating up to the parents:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

First argument passed onClick is the event itself:

```
function onChildClick(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('The link was clicked.');
}
```

Comment: Same here. onClildClick() function is not being triggered

Comment: @ShobikaBabu You need to add onPress prop, for example <View onPress={e => e.stopPropagation()}>

Answer (score 3):

You can simply set the parents pointerEvents property to 'box-none'. By doing so, the parent will not respond to touch events but its child views will get clicked.

```
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback
      pointerEvents={'box-none'}
  >
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
          onPress={()=>{
              //onPress here will work
          }}
      />
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to "swallow" the click event somewhere.  It could be in your outer `TouchableWithoutFeedback` (ie: change `onPress={()=> this.onParentClick()}` to `onPress={(e) => e.preventDefault()}` or you could wrap your TouchableOpacity in another touch handler, like below.

```html
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={()=> this.onParentClick()}>
  <View>
    <Text>How to prevent parent click event</Text>
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={(event)=> this.onChildClick(event)>
        <Text> Click Me </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  </View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you described works as expected. This is because `TouchableOpacity` is a child component of `TouchableWithoutFeedback`, and so the click event propagates up the tree, triggering the click event of `TouchableWithoutFeedback`. To solve this issue, there is an `event.stopPropagation()` method you can call, which will stop the event from bubbling up.

Something like this should work.

`onChildClick = (event)=>{
 //do your logic here
 event.stopPropagation();
}`

Comment: onChildClick() function is not being triggered. I always triggers onParentClick().

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to use onTouchEnd not press

This would be the simplest answer:

use this on the inner view at the point where you want the propagation to stop

```
onTouchEnd={(e) => {
   e.stopPropagation()
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue, resolved it simply by using zIndex, not only it helped me capture child's onPress but also parent's onPress too, I was able to perform two different operations in a single component

Comment: Should we add zIndex to child or parent?

Comment: I didn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

A trigger method:

```
const childPresses = {}
if(canChildPress) {
  childPresses.onPress = (event) => {this.onChildClick(event)}
}

return <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={()=> this.onParentClick()}>
  <View>
    <Text>How to prevent parent click event</Text>
    <TouchableOpacity {...childPresses} >
      <Text> Click Me </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **TouchableOpacity** from **gesture handler**

```
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
```

then **change your style to containerStyle** instead

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onPress} containerStyle={styles.container}>
```

everything should look good now...